# uninitialized constant SessionsController ROR rails 4

Tags: authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

Hi I am beginner to Ruby on rails. I am trying to some experiments. I am trying to implement user login. I am not using any gem. I tried that in following way :

```
get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "log_out"
  get "log_in" => "sessions#new", :as => "log_in"
  get "sign_up" => "users#new", :as => "sign_up"
  root :to => "users#new"
  resources :users
  resources :sessions

class SessionController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

   def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
    if user
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
      render "new"
    end
  end

   def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged out!"
  end

end
```

when I tried to hit `http://localhost:3000/log_in` It showed

```
uninitialized constant SessionsController
routing error
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Need some Help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `SessionController` not `SessionsController`. Either change it to `SessionsController` or edit your `routes` as below.

```
get "log_out" => "session#destroy", :as => "log_out"
get "log_in" => "session#new", :as => "log_in"
get "sign_up" => "users#new", :as => "sign_up"
root :to => "users#new"
resources :users
resource :session
```

I suggest changing the `SessionController` to `SessionsController`.

***IMP Note:***

While changing `SessionController` to `SessionsController`, don't forget to change the ***file name*** to **`sessions_controller.rb`**